# DLL load failed on Windows libm2k

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, python-bindings

I have been attempting to use the libm2k module on Windows, but I keep encountering the following error :

```
import _libm2k
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _libm2k: The specified module could not be found.
```

The version I installed is :

`libm2k-0.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

Is there any way I can resolve this error?